# Variables not accessible by whole panel

Tags: java, swing, scope, paintcomponent

I want to get two parameters[a,b] in [setpoints] function from the form and use them in paintcomponent to draw with.the problem is that two variables is not accessible  by the whole panel.they only accessible  by [setpoints] function

Here is the code of the panel:

```
public class shape extends javax.swing.JPanel  {

public int a;
public int b;

public shape() {
    initComponents();

 } 
 public void setpoints(int x0,int y0)
 {
     this.a=x0;
    this.b=y0;

 }

 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

   g.setColor(Color.blue); 
    g.drawLine(a, b, a,b);

 }
 }
```

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame  {

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

}
 public float p1;
public float p2;
public float p3;
public float p4;

 public void drawline1(){
     int k = 0;
     float x = p1;
     float y = p2;
    float DX = p3 - p1;
    float DY = p4 - p2;
    float m=DY/DX;
    int rx,ry;

    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Round(X)");
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("Round(Y)");
    table.getTableHeader().repaint(); 
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    model.addRow(new Object[]{k, x, y, x, y});
    shape s=new shape();
   s.setpoints((int)x, (int)y);

    do{
        if(DX>DY){
            k++;
            x++;
            y=y+m;
            rx=Math.round(x);
            ry=Math.round(y);
            model.addRow(new Object[]{k, rx, ry, x, y}); 
           s.setpoints(rx, ry);
        }
        if(DY>DX){
            k++;
            y++;
            x=x+(1/m);
            rx=Math.round(x);
            ry=Math.round(y);
            model.addRow(new Object[]{k, rx, ry, x, y}); 
          s.setpoints(rx, ry);
        }

    }
    while(y < p4 && x < p3); 
     }
```

Comment: Please post your [mcve] (please read the link).

Comment: Did you call `repaint` after calling `setpoints`, because based on you limited code snippet, it should work

Comment: I call function setpoints in the form and send Parameters but variables values of a & b exists only in setpoints function but have value of zero outside the function so,they can't assign value in paintcomonent

Comment: **Again**, if you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. But only do this if you want decent help quickly.

Comment: i edited the code.i just only want to get values of parameters from the form to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks to be located here:

```
public void drawline1() {
    int k = 0;
    float x = p1;
    // ..... etc

    shape s = new shape(); // ******  HERE ******
```

You're creating a new shape object within the drawline1 method and are making changes to its state  by changing the values held by its internal fields, but this shape object does not appear to be displayed anywhere in the GUI, and so making changes to its state will likely have no effect on any shape objects that are displayed in the GUI.

The solution is **NOT** to create a new shape object within this method, but rather to **obtain a reference to the shape object that is currently being displayed in the GUI**, and then **making changes to the state fields if this displayed shape object**.

How you do this key process is something we can't answer because we don't know where or how you're displaying the visualized shape object or what variables currently hold reference to this displayed shape object. So your job is to find out which variables these are, and then to pass their value to the class that holds this `drawline1()` method, and thereby allow the method to mutate the state of the displayed shape object.

Other suggestions:

- Learn and follow Java naming conventions, for instance all class names should begin with an upper case letter, so `public class Shape` not `public class shape`. This matters since it will make it much easier for others (us! your teachers) to understand your code.
- Learn about view / logic separation including M-V-C which stands for Model-View-Controller. If you can re-factor your code so that the logical code is in its own class, it becomes much easier to debug and fix these types of errors.